# how to modify the 2 dimantion array in to 4 dimension to feed into CNN

Tags: cnn

i am new to python I have an array train_x(887,20) how to convert it in to 4 dimension to feed into CNN

Comment: Would you mind explaining your dimensions? What are they for?